# Compute multiple disk usage percentage with graphite

Tags: graphite, collectd

I have metrics like theses:

```
collectd.host.df-root.df_complex-used
collectd.host.df-root.df_complex-free
collectd.host.df-root.df_complex-reserved
collectd.host.df-var.df_complex-used
collectd.host.df-var.df_complex-free
collectd.host.df-var.df_complex-reserved
```

I want to have the free / (free + used + reserved) on every disk (df-var and df-root : `collectd.host.df-*`): that is to say the % of free space on every disk.

I came up with this solution (that is not working):

```
groupByNode(group(aliasByNode(collectd.host.df-*.df_complex-free,2),groupByNode(collectd.host.df-*.df_complex-*,2,"sumSeries")),0,"asPercent")
```

Comment: Do something like- `scale(divideSeries(collectd.host.df-root.df_complex-free, addSeries(collectd.host.df-root.*)),100)` for both.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The idea is not to add something twice, but rather to have all disks covered (because it may have 3, 4 or 5 disks).

Answer (score 1):

You can enable "ValuesPercentage True" in collectd.conf for df plugin, start collectd service, then you can see ollectd.host.df-var.percent_bytes-used.value.

Answer (score 1):

The solution you have tried is not giving the correct result because the asAverage function, for the total, is taking into account the used value twice (i.e. the total is used + used + free + reserved).

Try this:

```
groupByNode(group(aliasByNode(collectd.host.df-*.df_complex-used,2),groupByNode(collectd.host.df-*.df_complex-{reserved,free},2,"sumSeries")),0,"asPercent")
```

It excludes the used metric from the second group.